# Check if a string contains only given characters

Tags: python, string

I'm wondering if there is more elegant way to check if the string (str = 'abcccbbaabcbca') contains only 'a','b' or 'c' than iterating over it :

```
for i in str:
   if i in ['a','b','c']:
      pass
   else :
      print('wrong character')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression:

```
if any(c not in 'abc' for c in _str):  # Don't use str as a name.
    print('Wrong character')
```

Comment: Note to the OP: You can check the contrary using `all` and removing the `not` : `all(c in ('a', 'b', 'c') for c in _str) -> True`

Answer (score 8):

Convert both strings to sets and check if they are equal. If yes, your string contains `a` AND `b` AND `c`:

```
valid = set(your_string) == set('abc')...
```

Use `issubset` to check if it contains ANY of a, b, c:

```
valid = set(your_string) <= set('abc')
```

or

```
valid = set(your_string).issubset('abc')
```

Subtract the sets to find out invalid characters:

```
bad_chars = set('abcXYcba') - set('abc') # set(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 7):

Using regular expressions:

```
import re
if re.search('[^abc]', string):
    print('wrong character')
```

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to mock, since this jumps directly to a regular expression, but test for matching against `"^[abc]+$"`

```
re.match('^[abc]+$', 'string')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `string.translate`:

```
import string

s = 'abcccbbaabcbca'
# translate character to empty ""
t = string.maketrans("","")

# if non-abc character is found s.translate will become the bad characters
if s.translate(t, 'abc'):
    print ('wrong character')
```

#### Updated

As also pointed out from @PadraicCunningham

`# for one off usage, you can skip making a translation table.`

`if s.translate(None, 'abc'):`
`…`

Comment: you just need `if s.translate(None, 'abc')`

Comment: True! its there for completeness.